# eliminate selected column of elements from a list of lists

Tags: list

I have a list of lists where each individual list has 3 elements. Something like this:

```
[[928.7, 554.29999958311, 0], 
[928.7, 558.15990063549, 0], 
[914.1, 558.15990063549, 0], 
[914.1, 554.29999958311, 0]]
```

How can I delete all the elements from a particular column? For example if I input "1" that will delete the first column, if I input "2" it will delete the second one and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your question regards pyhton...

I would try something like the following (using numpy):

```
    import numpy as np

    initial_list = [[928.7, 554.29999958311, 0], 
                    [928.7, 558.15990063549, 0], 
                    [914.1, 558.15990063549, 0], 
                    [914.1, 554.29999958311, 0]]

    # transform the list in a numpy array
    a = np.array(initial_list)

    # remove the column you want and put the output in a new variable
    a1 = np.delete(a, 0, 1) # this would the remove the first column(0)
                            #+the second "1" in the arguments tells to 
                            #+numpy to delete the column instead of the
                            #+ row.

    # convert back to a plain list
    final_list = a1.tolist()
```

If you want to stay with plain python, I would suggest something like:

```
    initial_list = [[928.7, 554.29999958311, 0], 
                    [928.7, 558.15990063549, 0], 
                    [914.1, 558.15990063549, 0], 
                    [914.1, 554.29999958311, 0]]

    for row in initial_list:
        del row[0]  # This would delete the first column from your matrix


    final_list = initial_list
```

Pay attention to the fact that the latter method will "overwrite" the original list and you will loose all the deleted data. Consider, if you need, to create a copy of the initial_list:

```
    initial_list_bck[:] = initial_list[:]
    # or
    initial_list_bck = initial_list.copy()
    # The following would create only a pointer to the first list
    initial_list_bck = initial_list
```

Hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list of lists. White iterating, remove the nth item.

```
a = [[928.7, 554.29999958311, 0],
[928.7, 558.15990063549, 0],
[914.1, 558.15990063549, 0],
[914.1, 554.29999958311, 0]]

column_number = 1

for i in range(0, len(a)):
   a[i].remove(a[i][column_number])

print a
```

Comment: This answer certainly is worth a little explanation!

Comment: Good job! hope the nicest OP like it ;)